# Salesforce tab buttons automation using webdriver

Tags: automation, webdriver, salesforce

I am novice for webdriver & selenium & While automating the Salesforce page I want to **click** `Account_Tab`. I am using `driver.findElement(By.id("Account_Tab")).click();`
All I can do is see it is enable with

```
if driver.findElement(By.id("Account_Tab")).isEnabled())
```

What am I missing that not allowing me to click on that tab. Please see HTML for more details:

```
    <ul id= "`enter code here`tabBar" class="zen-inlineList zen-tabMenu">
<li id="home_Tab" class="brandPrimaryBgr primaryPalette zen-active zen-firstItem primaryPalette">
<li id="Account_Tab">
<a title="Accounts Tab" href="/001/o">Accounts</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try **clicking on the Accounts tab** by using either of the following codes:

**1-** `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='Account_Tab']/a")).click();`
This will locate the **'a' element under 'li' element with id 'Account_Tab'** and click on it.

**2-** `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Accounts Tab']")).click();`
This will locate the **'a' element with title 'Accounts Tab'** and click on it.

**3-** `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Accounts']")).click();`
This will locate the **'a' element with exact innerHTML/text as 'Accounts'** and click on it.

Comment: @Shubh thank you xpath worked for me.I was looking for xpath but I am not sure how to find\create can you please give me pointers for it. Thanks again.

Comment: @ksj: This link will help you out in creating proper xpaths and/or css-selectors: [https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/)